# Limit number of characters of a text field

Tags: sqlite

I want a field "name" be long at most 20 characters...is it possible in sqllite?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.  Per [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html),

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type
>   name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not
>   impose any length restrictions (other than the large global
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric
>   values.

Answer (score 49):

Yes with CHECK CONSTRAINTS. Here is an example enforcing TEXT datatype with a length of less than or equal to 20 characters.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "test"
(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL
    CHECK(
        typeof("name") = "text" AND
        length("name") <= 20
    )
);

INSERT INTO "test" ("name") VALUES ("longer than twenty characters");
```

Result:

```
Error: CHECK constraint failed: test
```

Probably too late to help the OP but maybe someone else will find this useful.

Comment: Would you please tell me the limit of TEXT. I mean, does TEXT have some limit may be 10000 characters?

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this macro is 1 billion (10^9). You can change this value, but this is the default.

Comment: This saved me so much extra time. I really wish SQLite would update their docs to make it clearer.